# What am I missing? I am getting some array error

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am trying to convert a c program to shell. But I am getting errors.
Here is the program:

```
$bt[]
$pri[]
$pp[]
$temp


echo "Enter the number of processes: "
read n
for((i=1;i<=n;i++));
do
  pp[$i] = $i;
  echo "Enter the Burst Time & Priority of Process: "
        #scanf("%d %d",&bt[i], &pri[i]);
  read bt[$i]
  read pri[$i]
 echo $i
done

for((i=1;i<=n;i++));
do
  for((k=i+1; k<n; k++));
  do
    if(pri[$i] -gt pri[$k])
      then
      echo "(string comparison)"
      temp=pp[$i]
      pp[$i]=pp[$k]
      pp[$k]=temp
      temp=bt[$i]
      bt[$i]=bt[$k]
      bt[$k]=temp
      temp=pri[$i]
      pri[$i]=pri[$k]
      pri[$k]=temp
    fi
  done
done

wt[0] = 0
tat[0] = bt[0]
for((i=1; i<n; i++));
  do
      wt[$i] = tat[$i-1]
      tat[$i] = wt[$1] +bt[$i]
  done
echo -e "\nPROCESS\t\tPRIORITY\tBURST TIME\tWAITING TIME\tTURNAROUND TIME"
for((i=1; i<=n; i++));
do
  #echo -e "%s \t\t %s \t\t %s \t\t %s \t\t %s " "p[i],pri[i],bt[i],wt[i],tat[i]"
echo -e "${p[i]} \t\t ${pri[i]} \t\t ${bt[i]} \t\t ${wt[i]} \t\t ${tat[i]} "
done
```

Please help. I don't know the syntext of bash programming.

Comment: There are too many syntactical issues in this code for us to be able to correct them all for you without rewriting the whole code.  I would suggest that you start from scratch and write incrementally instead. Write a short piece of code, test it to see that it does the correct thing, and then expand upon it.  You will find the shell syntax checking service at https://www.shellcheck.net/ helpful to locate problematic pieces of code (try pasting in your current code there).

Comment: It also looks as if you are translating from some low-level programming language.  You seem to do some sorting of three arrays, for example.  This would be much easier to handle if the data was in a file with three columns that you sent to `sort` rather than manually inputted by a user interactively.  Most of the fine-grained loops would be better handled in an `awk` program than in the shell.  The shell is a _very bad_ programming language to do a 1-to-1 C code translation into.

Comment: If you don't know Bash syntax, why are you trying to write a Bash program? How do you expect people to help you? You mention "some array error". Are we supposed to guess which error(s) you get?

Comment: @berndbausch it says,
main.sh: line 39: wt[0]: command not found
main.sh: line 40: tat[0]: command not found
main.sh: line 43: wt[1]: command not found
main.sh: line 44: tat[1]: command not found


I have defined the arrays. But every time when I try to assign values, I am getting errors.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks a lot. I have fixed the errors and it's working now.
shellcheck.net is really awesome.

Comment: `wt[0] = 0` and the other similar lines suffer from a common error. **To make an assignment, put no white space around the equals sign**. If you do, the shell thinks you want to run a program named `wt[0]` with two parameters `=` and `0`. Since there are no such programs, you get the error. It's not really an array error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess no one going to answer this. Ok, Here is the answer. I took help from @Kusalananda to solve the errors.

```
#!/bin/bash
${bt[]}
${pri[]}
${pp[]}
$temp
${wt[]}
${tat[]}

echo "Enter the number of processes: "
read -r n
for((i=1;i<=n;i++));
do
  pp[$i]=$i
  echo "Enter the Burst Time & Priority of Process: "
        #scanf("%d %d",&bt[i], &pri[i]);
  read -r bt[$i]
  read -r pri[$i]
 echo "$i"
done

for((i=1;i<=n;i++));
do
  for((k=i+1; k<n; k++));
  do
    if("${pri[$i]}-gt${pri[$k]}")
      then
      echo "(string comparison)"
      temp=${pp[$i]}
      pp[$i]=${pp[$k]}
      pp[$k]=temp
      temp=${bt[$i]}
      bt[$i]=${bt[$k]}
      bt[$k]=temp
      temp=${pri[$i]}
      pri[$i]=${pri[$k]}
      pri[$k]=temp
    fi
  done
done

wt[0]=0
tat[0]=${bt[0]}
for((i=1; i<n; i++));
  do
      wt[$i]=${tat[$i-1]}
      tat[$i]=${wt[1]}+${bt[$i]}
  done
echo -e "\nPROCESS\t\tPRIORITY\tBURST TIME\tWAITING TIME\tTURNAROUND TIME"
for((i=1; i<=n; i++));
do
  #echo -e "%s \t\t %s \t\t %s \t\t %s \t\t %s " "p[i],pri[i],bt[i],wt[i],tat[i]"
echo -e "${pp[i]} \t\t ${pri[i]} \t\t ${bt[i]} \t\t ${wt[i]} \t\t ${tat[i]} "
done
```

Thanks. The credit goes to https://www.shellcheck.net/ and [programming boss](https://www.programmingboss.com/).

Comment: The code may be syntactically correct now, but much of it does not make any sense. Not, for example, that the `if` statement `if("${pri[$i]}-gt${pri[$k]}")` runs whatever `"${pri[$i]}-gt${pri[$k]}"` expands to as a command, and that the expansions at the start of the code won't do anything at all (it looks as if you intended to declare the variables, which you don't normally do in shell script).